# change table items with jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table which contains these values:
     `call_status = 1` for open tickets
     `call_status = 2` for closed tickets
     `call_status = 3` for InProcess tickets
     `call_status = 4` for deleted tickets.
now what I want to do is to add 4 radio buttons in top of the table which people can choose which tickets to show in the table instead of opening a new page, because each of these ticket values have their own web page which I don't like it.

This is my `call_status` row Code:

```
echo "<td style='text-align: center;'><a href='call_edit.php?call_id=$call_id'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='ویراش'></i></a><td>$call_id</td>\n<td style='width:100px;'>$call_first_name</td>\n</td>\n";


if($call->call_status == 0){

echo "<td>باز</td>\n";
}
if($call->call_status == 1){

echo "<td>بسته</td>\n";
}
if($call->call_status == 2){

echo "<td>در حال بررسی</td>\n";
}
if($user_level <> 1){
if($call->call_status == 3){

echo "<td>حذف شده</td>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you struggling? Can you post your code so we can help you?

Comment: @Chris added to post

Answer (score 0):

Ok so when you create your table rows you want to add more information to the rows. So what I normally do is this: I add a general class like for example

```
class="status_row_elem"
```

then you also want to add the status of the row as attribute like this:

```
data-status="<?=$status?>"
```

Ok now that you have more information to work with in your rows it is pretty easy to manipulate the rows to do whatever you want. You can do an onchange on your radio buttons to look something like this:

You just need to give your select an id

```
$("#call_status").change(function(){
    var call_status = $(this).val();
    $(".status_row_elem").hide(); //you hide all the rows
    $(".status_row_elem[data-status="+call_status+"]").show(); //show the call status you selected
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2td20co/

Comment: i dont get the first part of `data-status="<?=$status?>".`

Comment: It is the call status of the row. So if the ticket is open it will look like this:<tr class="status_row_elem" data-status="1">

Comment: so you mean I add a calss and a data-status to the call_status Row in table?

Comment: check the post again I corrected the table row code.

Comment: I still dont get this part? `data-status="<?=$status?>"` what should I do with this?

Comment: For you it would be `data-status="<?=$call->call_status?>"` on the tr element. Because you need that information. `<?=` is just shorthand for `<php echo`

Comment: ok now how to make it work when i change the radio buttons? like this? : `<input type="radio" data-status="0" name="radio"  >باز </input>`

Comment: Can you use any of the chatrooms yet? Or I guess you still need rep? Let me invite you and try. Else we can use another site to chat on, because I think it is better if we can talk live

Comment: yea i dont have enough reps